# Scale image in ImageView to width of the parent and scale in height accordingly

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview, scale

Put all in one file to make it more clear, together with code and result:

Comment: it doesnt work... check update

Comment: as your requirement is not a std scaleType use scaleType="matrix" and compute the Matrix to match your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@drawable/image1"/>
```

**edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="right" >

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**edit2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works but its like using dp in height, only this time I take 1/10 of the whole height.
also I need a relative layout because i need to draw multiple images one on another later

Comment: u can design with a linear layout too..by setting orientation n with nested linear layouts.

Comment: ok thanks for the help anyways, im accepting the answer for your effort :) too bad I couldnt get exactly what I wanted

Comment: glad to help u buddy..try with linear layout if dint work catch me again.. i ll defnetly help u to solve. :) n happy new year..

Answer (score 0):

Put the width of image view to "fill_parent".
It solves your problem too.

Comment: check out the current code and images... I don't know why I can't achieve what I want, maybe you can figure it out

Comment: did you use weight ?? if you are using linear layout please keep this thing in mind that use Weight.